# Parsing KML/XML with ElementTree library

Tags: python, xml, parsing, kml, elementtree

I would like to parse the "ID2" name attribute found in the SimpleData tag utilizing the ElementTree python library.

```
<Placemark>
    <ExtendedData>
        <SchemaData>
            <SimpleData name="ID1">123456</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="ID2">111111</SimpleData>
        </SchemaData>
    </ExtendedData>
</Placemark>
```

I've been trying something like

```
temp=root.findall(".//Folder/Placemark/ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name='ID2']")
```

Everything I found on stack overflow doesn't include the objects as with "name" examples.

Comment: Your KML document sets a default XML namespace that you need to take into account when looking for elements. There are lots of questions here on Stack Overflow dealing with parsing namespaced XML documents, and there is documentation [here](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) if you're using the lxml implementation of ElementTree.

Answer (score 2):

The namespace must be specified in the XPath expression if the XML uses namespaces.

The XPath expression can have the explicit namespace as part of the element name.

```
elems = root.find('{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Placemark')
```

Alternatively, the *.find()*, *findall()* and *iterfind()* functions can have an explicit namespace dictionary object as the second argument and the XPath can use the namespace prefix. This makes the expressions more compact and easier to read.

```
namespaces = {'kml': 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'}
elems = root.find('kml:Placemark', namespaces)
```

**Try:**

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Folder>
    <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData>
            <SchemaData>
                <SimpleData name="ID1">123456</SimpleData>
                <SimpleData name="ID2">111111</SimpleData>
            </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
    </Placemark>
  </Folder>
</kml>'''

namespaces = {'kml': 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'} # add more as needed

# uncomment to load data from file
#tree = ET.parse('simpledata.kml')
#root = tree.getroot()

root = ET.fromstring(data)
xpath = ".//kml:Placemark/kml:ExtendedData/kml:SchemaData/kml:SimpleData[@name='ID2']"
for elem in root.findall(xpath, namespaces):
    print("ID2=", elem.text)
```

**Output:**

```
 ID2=111111
```

See the [Parsing XML with Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces) section of the ElementTree documentation.